# How to connect laptop 1366x768 to FullHD monitor using VGA?

Tags: display, vga

I have laptop with 1366x768 resolution. I need to connect to external Dell monitor which supports FulHD resolution. While connecting with VGA cable - the resolution on external display is the same as on laptop. There's no option in Intel Graphips card software to set FullHD. How to fix that?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right display?  Have you got them set to clone mode, or extend?

Comment: Yes. Clone mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set it to Clone, then both monitors have to be the same resolution, so it won't allow you to set it higher than the smallest monitor.

You'll have to set it to Extended Desktop mode to have independent resolutions on each monitor.

[image]

More [info from Intel here](http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-031026.htm)